# Gtk How to add GtkMenu widget at end edge of widget

Tags: gtk

I have a GtkMenu Widget and i am adding it to screen on button click,,
but it gets added at mouse location but i want to add it to end edge of button widget like,

```
+-------+
|BUTTON |
+-------+
+------------+
|Menu Item 1 |
|Menu Item 2 |
+------------+
```

I am using following code to add popup menu

```
    // Add popup menu.
    gtk_menu_popup( GTK_MENU (widget), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,                    
                    bevent->button, bevent->time);
```

Ok added this function but popup menu gets added to end of window not at the end of button widget...

```
void set_position (GtkMenu *menu, gint *px, gint *py, gboolean *push_in, gpointer data)
{
    gint w, h;
    GtkBuilder *builder = GetBuilderPointer();
    GtkWidget *button = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "button_presence"));

    gdk_window_get_size (button->window, &w, &h);
    gdk_window_get_origin (button->window, px, py);
    *py = h;

    printf("\n\n w[%d] h[%d] px[%d] py[%d]\n\n", w, h, *px, *py );
    *push_in = TRUE;
}
```

Printf gives output like follows,
w[350] h[400] px[341] py[607]

i am not able to retrieve x, y, height, width of button widget...
Note: This button is a custom widget with (GtkHBox+(GtkImage+GtkLabel)) in it.

thanks unwind for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth argument to `gtk_menu_popup()` is a pointer to a `GtkMenuPositionFunc`, which is a callback that you can define. You need to add such a callback, and have it return the desired position, by reading it out of the button widget's GdkWindow.

It's been a while since I did this, but you might also have to read out the parent window's position on-screen, and add the widget's position to them to get the absolute coordinates where you want the menu to pop up.

Comment: Thanks, 
Added this function but still have some problems... please sea updated part in question.